# Site works in IE8 mode but above

Tags: html, css

I am baffled why http://www.imvuoutfits.com/search/ works in IE8 mode but not IE9 or IE10 standards.

I don't see anything wrong in the script console that indicates a javascript error, so I can only assume it has something to do with css. Works fine in firefox and chrome. I saw that IE10 complained about putting `select`'s in a td but thats required for the base script to work.

[image]

Compared to IE8 mode:
[image]

Comment: Next time, please go validate your code _before asking_: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.imvuoutfits.com/search/

Comment: I have validated all to specs, besides those I purposely choose to break specs, such as using width in td

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `</select>` in every `<td>`.

Comment: Thanks, chrome auto added them for me. I guess that's what I get for debugging in chrome and not using a validator.

Comment: If you want to debug your source code, you have to click on "view soruce". What you see in the developer tools is the "compiled" source code that chrome generated from your source code appending the html standard and some other things.